# jQuery - Animate menu active icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

The active class displays a dot icon above the list item. I would like it so that when you hover over another list item the icon slides left or right and stops in the correct position.

I have already added the JS to take the active class off and add it to the currently hovered item, but would very much appreciate help in animating this transition.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WgszM/

```
$(".desktop-menu li").hover(function(){
  $("ul li.active").removeClass('active');  
  $(this).stop().addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in order to have the effect you want, that is: the dot moving to another element, you are going to need to create an extra element which will move to where you hover.

So I suggest doing something like this:

```
$('ul li').hover( function() {
    var acl = $(this).offset();
    var aw = $(this).width();
    var ll = acl.left + parseInt( aw / 2 );
    var tt = acl.top - 8;
    $('#active').animate({
            left : ll + 'px',
            top : tt + 'px' 
        });
});
```

Here is the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/ec9cm/

Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm still having a problem with the position being displayed incorrectly when the page loads. The active div is positioned exactly to the left of the active list item rather than half its width. When I mouseover this is corrected.

Also, do you know how to change the animation duration?

Comment: I had a typo in my code. This now works perfectly. My updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WgszM/9/

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to replaced **'left'** attribute to **'marginLeft'** attribute.
You will see the difference and set pad/margin accordingly.

Have fun with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these style in your css then it only ANIMATE

```
header .desktop-menu .nav nav ul{
    position:absolute;
}
header .desktop-menu .nav nav ul li{
  position:relative;
}
```